# Restrict an already existing TypeScript interface (process.env)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to strongly type `ProcessEnv` by replacing its interface so there's no indexed access to arbitrary environment variables.

I know it can be extended with

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    var1?: string;
    var2?: string;
  }
}
```

but because `ProcessEnv` it's actually defined in `@types/node/index.d.ts`, the result it still maintains the indexed accessor like this:

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
  interface ProcessEnv {
    [key: string]: string | undefined; 
    var1?: string;
    var2?: string;
  }
}
```

How to remove it? Is it even possible?

```
process.env.var1 // ok
process.env.var2 // ok
process.env.var3 // not ok, I want it to be an error but it gives a string due to the index accessor
```

What I usually do is defining a new interface with the same definition but removing the field to be redefined with `Omit` and then add it again... but since this is a global variable, I cannot use a different interface for it (unless I find all instances of `process.env` and cast it to the new type, which is something I don't want to do).

Comment: I guess there's this... so probably no way to do it right now? https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36146

Answer (score 0):

You may try to turn on [`noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature) flag. Though it will affect all your code, ofcourse. Not just the `ProcessEnv` type:

```ts
interface Env {
  [k: string]: string | undefined
}

interface Env {
  var1: string
  var2: string
}

declare const env: Env

env.var1
env.var2
env.var3 // error
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8n6N)

Looks like there is a bug in TS playground where it doesn't store the state of compilation flags in the link. Maybe you'll have to go to `TS Config` and turn on `noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature` manually.

Comment: that's a good point, but it's not viable right now (not a new project at work, so... lot of impact) Would be nice to be able to enable those flags for certain lines, ts-lint:disable style...